# Reload or refresh Livewire Powergrid on submit of form component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-powergrid

I am submitting one form via Livewire submit and then I need to refresh a table(Powergrid Livewire).

in blade view, below is component for dataTable.

```
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <livewire:broker.brokers-api-data-table />
            </div>
```

Now when I submit a form, it goes to another component, `AddBrokerModal` and below is submit action when submit is clicked,

```
    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate();
        DB::transaction(function () {
            $data = [
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'brokerlist_id' => $this->brokerlist_id,
            ];

        BrokerApi::create($data);

        // Emit a successful event with a message
        $this->dispatch('success', __('New broker created'))->to(BrokersApiDataTable::class);
    
        $this->reset();
        });

    }
```

Now, I want to refresh `brokers-api-data-table`  component when this form is submitted and successful dispatch occurs.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dispatching a *success* event to your grid, you will have a public method to manage that event:

```php
....
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
....

final class UserTable extends PowerGridComponent
{
    #[On('success')]
    public function manageSuccess()
    {
        /* do something*/
    }
.....
```

when the method *manageSuccess* is called a refresh of the component is executed.

Otherwise if you don't need to *"do something" other*, you can simply send a *pg:eventRefresh-default* event instead of *success* (the *-default* ending is the default-table-name, change it as needed):

```php
// AddBrokerModal
public function submit()
{
   .....

   BrokerApi::create($data);

   $this->dispatch('pg:eventRefresh-default')->to(BrokersApiDataTable::class);
    
   $this->reset();
}
```

A third option is to send a more generic *$refresh* event:

```php
// AddBrokerModal::submit()

$this->dispatch('$refresh')->to(BrokersApiDataTable::class);
```

In this case I think you must add *$refresh* to the listeners:

```php
// BrokersApiDataTable
final class UserTable extends PowerGridComponent
{
    protected $listeners = [
      '$refresh'
    ];

.....
```

Comment: 1st option worked well with success msg :-)

Answer (score 0):

With my experience, in your `AddBrokerModal` component's `submit()` method, after dispatching the success event, you can emit a custom event to trigger the refresh in `brokers-api-data-table` component... something like this:

**AddBrokerModal component:**

```
use Livewire\Component;

class AddBrokerModal extends Component
{
    public function submit()
    {
        // Form submission logic.
        // Dispatch success event.
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('refreshDataTable');
        // Reset form fields.
        $this->reset();
    }
}
```

**brokers-api-data-table component:**

```
use Livewire\Component;

class BrokersApiDataTable extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['refreshDataTable'];

    public function refreshDataTable()
    {
        // Logic to refresh the table data.
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.broker.brokers-api-data-table');
    }
}
```

Comment: actually table is Powergrid tables, https://livewire-powergrid.com/get-started/create-powergrid-table.html so there is no render function in the table component, so that's why I am curious how to re-render that table with new data once form submitted.